# Unity C# How to check if library is existing in the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to check if unity library exists in the project with scripts.
For example:

```
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
```

And if it exists then make some actions like:

```
Advertisements.IsReady();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the library is not referenced in your project the compiler should complain about `Advertisements.IsReady();` and notifies you that `using UnityEngine.Advertisements;` is a not used reference or doesnt know what you try to refernce to.

Comment: Yes, but I want to make script to do actions only then if library exists, if it's not then no actions would be taken.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, does this help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) about the method `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`. This method returns an `AssemblyName[]` containing the names for all the assemblies referenced by this assembly. In other words the referenced assemblies are e.g. a library. Then you can easily wrap your a code in an `if` statement to either execute the code if your desired library (name) is contained in the array or to not execute.

Sample code:

```
Assembly currentAssembly = typeof(/*enter the class name which contains the assembly references*/).Assembly;

AssemblyName[] referencedAssemblies =  currentAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

foreach (var refAssembly in referencedAssemblies)
{
    if (assembly == /*the name of the assembly you want to check that has to exist*/)
    {
        //...do your work if the assembly exists

        break;
    }
}
```

The technique behind this is called `Reflection` which I can highly recommend you to read about, its quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use if else statement in this case because the compiler will complain about this, for example `if(false) Advertisements.IsReady();` compiler cannot find type Advertisements.

But theres another way, you can use Reflection to get Type from the assembly. and then get the method to call, but still this is not the practical way.

You may want to use constant instead, or use ClassAttribute to tell that this script enable for advertisements, but `using UnityEngine.Advertisements;` is a must, you can create custom monobehaviour for this, and then inherit it to your application so that you can hide this line `using UnityEngine.Advertisements;`